# How to make Rust JNI bindings with Bazel

Tags: java, rust, java-native-interface, bazel

## Introduction

I have a Rust library that I want to be able to call from Java through JNI. Using Maven, I can use it, but I'm stuck when I try to move to Bazel.

I run `bazel run //my_lib/java:java_binary` and I get the following

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rust_bindings in java.library.path: [/private/var/tmp/_bazel_XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/my_lib/java/java_binary.runfiles/__main__/my_lib/rust]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2680)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:807)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1907)
    at Main.<clinit>(Main.java:8)
```

which means the Rust shared library library isn't available. Indeed when I `tree /private/var/tmp/_bazel_XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/my_lib/java/java_binary.runfiles/__main__/my_lib`, I get

```
└── java
    ├── java_binary -> /private/var/tmp/_bazel_XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/stackoverflow/java/java_binary
    └── java_binary.jar -> /private/var/tmp/_bazel_XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/execroot/__main__/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/stackoverflow/java/java_binary.jar
```

How come bazel doesn't build the Rust shared library despite the fact it's a dependancy of the Java binary?

## The code

```sh
$ tree .
├── java
│   ├── BUILD.bazel
│   ├── Main.class
│   └── Main.java
└── rust
    ├── BUILD.bazel
    ├── CARGO
    │   └── BUILD.bazel
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── lib.rs
```

`java/Main.java`

```java
public class Main {

    static native void rust();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("rust_bindings");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello from Java");
        rust();
    }
}
```

`java/BUILD.bazel`

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@rules_java//java:defs.bzl", "java_binary")

java_binary(
    name = "java_binary",
    srcs = glob(["*.java"]),
    main_class = "Main",
    deps = [
        "//my_lib/rust:rust_bindings"
    ],
)
```

`rust/Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "rust_bindings"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[lib]
name="rust_bindings"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
jni = "0.19.0"
```

`rust/src/lib.rs`

```rust
use jni::JNIEnv;
use jni::objects::{JClass, JString};

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "system" fn Java_Main_rust(env: JNIEnv,class: JClass)
{
    println!("Hello from Rust");
}
```

`rust/BUILD.bazel`

```
package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])

load("@rules_rust//rust:defs.bzl", "rust_shared_library")
load("//cargo:crates.bzl", "all_crate_deps")

rust_shared_library(
    name = "rust_bindings",
    srcs = glob(["src/**/*.rs"]),
    edition = "2018",
    deps = all_crate_deps(), // Import the JNI crate using Bazel
)
```

---

Edit: simplified the code

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to make it work with `rust_shared_library`, so as workaround I wrapped it in `cc_binary` (relevant [commit](https://github.com/dkomanov/stuff/commit/1153115dbedb66b2913c4bb831affead16764d15#diff-cba8bd345e90e68e3ffcd2f780b14ebfc10db38de7ec1210d5632303b895615aR14)).

In your example try to change `rust/BUILD.bazel`:

```
load("@rules_rust//rust:defs.bzl", "rust_shared_library")
load("//cargo:crates.bzl", "all_crate_deps")

rust_shared_library(
    name = "rust_lib",
    srcs = glob(["src/**/*.rs"]),
    edition = "2018",
    deps = all_crate_deps(), // Import the JNI crate using Bazel
)

cc_binary(
    name = "rust_bindings",
    linkshared = True,
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [":rust_lib"],
)
```